# capture all the audit logs for any CRUD operations happens to any of my rest controller

Tags: spring-boot

Here is my requirement:

**Need to capture all the audit logs for any CRUD operations happens to any of my rest controller**

Some facts about my current application:

1. spring boot application
2. multiple micro-services (start with we have 2) and each have its own rest controller
3. already implemented JPA AuditingEntityListener

Since my app involves multiple micro-services, I need to build the audit log service generically.  Also, please note that we plan to deploy our app in Cloud foundry.  Also come across, CF has its own audit log service. So, can we plug in the CF audit log service in spring boot application which already implemented JPA auditiable entity?

Any suggestions are welcome

thanks
sen

Comment: which cloud foundry instance are you using PCF, SAP CF etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Javers Spring Boot Integration](https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/). It is designed as a framework for auditing changes in your object-oriented data.